# Is it possible to run selenium tests concurrently/parallel using same browser/platform combination

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to run tests in parallel using the same browser/platform combination, Chrome/WIN7 to be exact. We have managed to reduce our test execution times so far by running different features on separate executors (node) via jenkins. What I am trying to achieve is being able to run separate scenarios in parallel to reduce the test execution time further. Is this possible using selenium grid with all node having the same browser/platform combo?

Comment: Which programming lang are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using TestNG

Use `parallel="methods"` as below:-

```
<suite name="Test-method Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" >
```

Refer:-

http://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-executing-parallel-tests/

You can use more execution type according to your need :-

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">
```

Refer:-

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Is the only way to acheive this using TestNG? Is it possible to do this using MSTest?